# List of installed fonts that support a certain character

Tags: fonts, unicode

How can I find out which fonts on my system include coverage of a certain character, for example, U+2192?

I've tried looking in Character Map, but I don't see a way to query fonts by character, only characters by font.

Comment: I didn't give it enough time to test, but I hope if it doesn't work or still looking for better than that. Let me know, I may give it another try to search for other options.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For installed fonts which have the Unicode character U+2192, you could use `fc-list`:

```
fc-list :charset=2192
```

Example output:

> ```
> /usr/local/share/fonts/consolas/consolab.ttf: Consolas:style=Bold
> /usr/local/share/fonts/consolas/consolai.ttf: Consolas:style=Italic
> /usr/local/share/fonts/consolas/consola.ttf: Consolas:style=Regular
> /usr/local/share/fonts/consolas/consolaz.ttf: Consolas:style=Bold Italic
> /usr/share/fonts/opentype/cantarell/Cantarell-Bold.otf: Cantarell:style=Bold
> /usr/share/fonts/opentype/cantarell/Cantarell-ExtraBold.otf: Cantarell,Cantarell Extra Bold:style=Extra Bold,Regular
> ...
> /usr/share/texmf/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmsansquot8-oblique.otf: Latin Modern Sans Quotation,LM Sans Quot 8:style=8 Oblique,Bold Italic
> /usr/share/texmf/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmsansquot8-regular.otf: Latin Modern Sans Quotation,LM Sans Quot 8:style=8 Regular,Regular
> /usr/share/texmf/fonts/opentype/public/lm-math/latinmodern-math.otf: Latin Modern Math:style=Regular
> ```

For formatting the output, there is also a poorly documented `-f` format option. See `man FcPatternFormat` and the [fontconfig](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/fontconfig) documentation page which has a [list of some available properties](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/fontconfig/fontconfig-user.html#AEN21).

For example:

```
fc-list -f "%{file}\n\t%{family}\n" :charset=2192
```

Answer (score 5):

May be there other tools but `hb-shape` gives some results, Example (`\u2192`, `\u107`, `\u106` and `\u2191` respectively):

```
$ hb-shape .fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf "→"
[NULL=0+498]

$ hb-shape .fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf "ć"
[cacute=0+1054]

$ hb-shape .fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf "Ć"
[Cacute=0+1313]

$ hb-shape .fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf "↑"
[NULL=0+498]
```

As you notice, available ones results return with their Unicode name `Cacute` otherwise `NULL`.

I have entered Unicode using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> , or you may want this way for making shell script to loop through fonts:

```
$ hb-shape .fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf `echo -ne "\u2192"`
[NULL=0+498]
```

For reference, `hb-shape` is a test tool from [HarfBuzz Project](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/HarfBuzz/) a Unicode text shaping engine.

Comment: The output looks different now (I'm using hb-shape 1.0.1):
 $ hb-shape ./Roboto-Light.ttf `echo -ne "\u2192"`
[gid0=0+908]

Comment: @Étienne, that's quite old, using `sh-shape` 1.4.2 in Ubuntu 17.10, Robot-light.tff 2.000980, 2014, I get similar output `[.notdef=0+498]`. If that `gid0` is constant for all non-supported characters, then you can use it. Also I recommend to you asking directly in HarfBuzz mailing list. They are active developers.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, my comment was not a question. I just wanted to warn other people ghat the output looks different on other versions, but your solurion indeed worked and I upvoted it yesterday.